# Rename the tags [reportingservices-200x] to [reporting-services-200x]

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [`[reportingservices]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reportingservices) is synonym of [`[reporting-services]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reporting-services), but with the years e.g. [`[reporting-services-2005]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2005) becomes a synonym of [`[reportingservices-2005]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2005) instead. This is inconsistent.

Please reverse the synonym direction of some of these pairs. I think `[reporting-services-200x]` is canonical.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to post this as a comment, but it was just too messy.  We have:

- [reporting-services](/questions/tagged/reporting-services), which is good.
- [reporting-services-2012](/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2012), which is also good.
- [reportingservices-2000](/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2000), [reportingservices-2005](/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2005) and [reportingservices-2008](/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2008), which are all missing a hyphen between "reporting" and "services".

We also have [ssrs-reports](/questions/tagged/ssrs-reports), which appears to be the same as [reporting-services](/questions/tagged/reporting-services).

Then we also have [ssrs-2008](/questions/tagged/ssrs-2008) and [ssrs-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/ssrs-2008-r2) which have the same tag wiki entry stating they're for SQL Server 2008 R2 reporting services.

Finally, there's [ssrs-2012](/questions/tagged/ssrs-2012), which appears to be the same as [reporting-services-2012](/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2012).

So I think we need the following core tags, with the tags in parentheses merged in:

- [reporting-services](/questions/tagged/reporting-services) <- ([ssrs-reports](/questions/tagged/ssrs-reports))
- [reporting-services-2000](/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2000) <- ([reportingservices-2000](/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2000))
- [reporting-services-2005](/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2005) <- ([reportingservices-2005](/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2005))
- [reporting-services-2008](/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2008) <- ([reportingservices-2008](/questions/tagged/reportingservices-2008), [ssrs-2008](/questions/tagged/ssrs-2008), [ssrs-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/ssrs-2008-r2))
- [reporting-services-2012](/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2012) <- ([ssrs-2012](/questions/tagged/ssrs-2012))

Alternately, they can all start with **ssrs-[year]** if people think that makes more sense.

Comment: This is great, but I would add that's it's important to keep 2008 and 2008R2 as separate tags; the functionality between releases is different enough that it's useful to be able to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @IanPreston - you're most likely right, I skipped over SSRS-2008 (and R2) when they came out.  I know there's a fair difference between SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008R2, but I was trusting the tag wiki in this case, which was probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Also, `[ssrs-2008]` should be a synonym of `[reporting-services-2008]`, not the other way around.

It is [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssrs-2008/synonyms) at the moment in the wrong direction since you don't have a choice about that when proposing a synonym. That's also how the other synonyms ended up so inconsistently.